# Increasing fraction of sum of binomial coeffients

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Show that the quantity
$$ \displaystyle \frac{ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n { n+k \choose i-1 }  }{ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n { n+k+1 \choose i }  } $$

is non-decreasing in $k$, where $k \geq n$.